# VS2019 C++ CoCreateGuid linking issue

Tags: c++, winapi, guid, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a C++ console app. I provide code to create a GUID as part of the program. I'm getting the unresolved external for CoCreateGuid despite including the appropriate header and linking the correct library in linker->Additional Dependencies

```
Header: <objbase.h>
library: ole32.lib
```

This is info i found based on [CoCreateGuid linker issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e53ee934-591a-4a3f-bcaf-eba8d295c8f1/guid-lnk2019-error?forum=vclanguage)

and here:

[CoCreate GUID usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateguid)

Is there something additional that i may be missing?

This is/was an issue that was outside of the code, but in the linker as part of the vcxproj. It turns out that a nuget package that i was importing had the incorrect special character when trying to add an additional dependency. 
i had used $(AdditionalDependencies) rather than %(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: When you change the setting, be sure to look at the two comboboxes at the top of the dialog.  They need to be changed to "All" so the change is effective for every configuration and every platform.

Comment: That was one of the first things i verified. All platforms, all configurations.

Comment: [mcve] required, plus a full, verbatim error message.

Comment: Create a C++ console app from the project template in VS2019. Then add these lines to the app: `#include <objbase.h>

int main()
{
 GUID tGuid = {};
 CoCreateGuid(&tGuid);
}`. Can't reproduce this issue. The ole32.lib is included in template project. Can you try like what I did to see if it helps?

Comment: Please put a complete error message to the question.

Comment: All - I did not include a minimal reproducible example b/c the issue does not lie in the code itself, but rather project linkages which do not show up in the headers or source.

Comment: The exact error is:
1>GUIDTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoCreateGuid@4 referenced in function _main

and i have tracked it down to a nuget package that i am including that sets up static linking/additional dependencies. I have a suspiciscion that i am wiping my additional dependencies or something.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have added the correct library (ole32.lib) in linker->Additional Dependencies. To make sure the Visual Studio can find it in your local system you do the following check:

(Here I use Windows 10 and installed the latest SDK, version is 18362.)

- First you can search the ole32.lib in your local system to see if you can find it. For example in the following path:

[image]

- Second check the project properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories -> Evaluated value to see if it points to the right path showed in your search result like above.

[image]

Comment: I'm also using 18362, and i confirmed that ole32.lib is present in that directory. Finally, i confirmed that the VC_LibraryPath_x86 contains the correct path. I'm honestly surprised everything is in place as expected.

Comment: This is the only delta between release/debug that i have affected. In a nuget package targets file, i add the following:
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32' And $(Configuration.IndexOf('Debug')) != -1 And '$(Linkage-protobuf)' == 'static'">
        <Link>
            <AdditionalDependencies>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)lib\Win32\Debug\libprotobufd.lib;$(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>

Comment: It turns out my error in the protobuf package wiped out the additional dependencies for the linker.
$(AdditionalDependencies) should have been %(AdditionalDependencies) with the %, not the $